# How to add a UiBarButtonItem in UINavigationController for all viewControllers

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I wonder if it's possible to add a button directly into a `navigation controller`, or I have to add button from all `viewController` pushed into `navigation Controller`?

Example: I have 3 `UIViewController` (VC1, VC2 and VC3) and I can push this elements in a NavigationController (NC). If I need to add a button as right navigation item for VC1 I can write in `viewDidLoad` of VC1 :

```
UIBarButtonItem *settingsBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(settings)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingsBtn;
```

If I need this button on NC also for VC2 and VC3 I have to add this code in VC2 and VC3 too and specify method "settings" in VC1,VC2 and VC3

Is it possible to add this button in a shared way? And how can I define settings method as shared method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to have a parent class that your `UIViewController`s derive from. In the parent class, you can set the button in, say, `viewDidLoad`. In your children classes, you would do `[super viewDidLoad];` in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes is a fast and OOP solution :) i'll bring you up 900 reputation point :P thank you again donkim!

Comment: Glad to help! I've learned so much from this community and am glad to contribute back. :)

Answer (score 1):

Become a delegate of the UINavigationController.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated {
UIBarButtonItem *settingsBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Settings"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(settings)];
viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingsBtn;
}
```